# real_escape_string is not working for php oop

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I have two classes which are below:

class-1: connection_class.php

```
class connection{
public $connection;

function __construct(){
  $this->db_connect();
}

private function db_connect(){
  $this->conn = @ new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password');
     if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
       $this->connection = FALSE;
       $this->warn = '<br />Failed to connect database! Please try again later';
     }
}

}
```

and a loginclass:
class-2: login_class.php

```
class login{
private $conn;
    function __construct($con){
      if($con->connection==FALSE){
         echo $con->warn;
         exit();
      }else{
         $this->conn=$con->connection;
      }
   }

public function get_user($sql){
  $this->db_select('database_name');
  $result = $this->conn->query($logopt['sql']);
      if($result->num_rows>=1){
          return $result;
      }else{
          return FALSE;
      }
}
}
```

Now from login page:
Page: login.php

```
include_once('connection_class.php');
$con = new connection();

include_once('login_class.php');
$login = new login($con);

$sql= "SELECT * FROM access WHERE username='".real_escape_string($user_name)."' AND password='".$pass_word."'";
$user=$login->getuser($sql);
if($user){
   echo 'User found';
}else{
   echo 'User not found';
}
```

Here If I use real_escape_string($user_name) or mysqli_real_escape_string($user_name), login.php is showing following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function real_escape_string() in
>   ...........

How can I user real_escape_string in my case?

Comment: these classes are so riddled with either typo's or flat out syntax errors it's difficult to provide assistance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are wrapping your mysqli connection in another class, you will need to expose a method for calling `real_escape_string` in your connection class.

eg:

```
class connection{
  public $connection;

  function __construct(){
    $this->db_connect();
  }

  private function db_connect(){
    $this->conn = @ new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
      $this->connection = FALSE;
      $this->warn = '<br />Failed to connect database! Please try again later';
    }
  }

  public function real_escape_string($string) {
    // todo: make sure your connection is active etc.
    return $this->conn->real_escape_string($string);
  }
}
```

And then, change

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM access WHERE username='".real_escape_string($user_name)."' AND password='".$pass_word."'";
```

to

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM access WHERE username='".$con->real_escape_string($user_name)."' AND password='".$pass_word."'";
```

Bonus comment: your `login` class isn't actually using your connection to run queries. You need to fix that (specifically: `$this->db_select('database_name');`).

Comment: Thankyou very much....It is working now. But my login class is using my connection to run queries. Because here in my code I escaped a method of loginclass which is: private function db_select($db){
    $this->conn->select_db($db);
}

Comment: @wadeshuler why? For fun? To learn? There are myriad reasons. Learning to do it yourself actually helps you make educated decisions on what if any frameworks to use. Tldr: Stop hating for the sake of hating.

Comment: I am not saying you shouldn't know, or learn, how to do it by hand. Once you have passed having the knowledge and ability to code it yourself, you should try a framework. They save TONS of time, and save the client TONS of money. Why re-code your login, signup, forgot password over and over again for every project your on? Frameworks add organization and allow to easily extend the project. If you use a framework, follow MVC best practices, and follow a PSR, it will go a long way. Nobody likes to go into another system and see spaghetti code and junk tucked all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add `msql_` at the beginning of the function the correct function is `mysql_real_escape_string();` use this instead of `real_escape_string();` as stated above.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: he's not using mysql. so this is wrong. if you change it to `mysqli`, it's the same as the answer from @panther

Comment: @pala_1 please check the php manual their is no `mysqli_real_escape_string`  method you have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` method in any case else you have to use `sqlite_escape_string` method or if you wanna user `msqli` then you have to use `mysqli_escape_string` method this method is an alias of `mysqli_real_escape_string` method

Comment: you are wrong, in every way. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php  You say there is no `mysqli_real_escape_string`, but then go on to say there is another function, that is an alias of that non-existent function? You say to read the manual, which very explicitly states that there is a `mysqli_real_escape_string`? your answer is wrong. it will not work.

Comment: i think you haven't read and understand my whole comment. please read the last two line. @ pala_1

Comment: I think you don't understand php. read the link i posted. the one that says you dont know what you're talking about.

Comment: Downvoted for mysql. It has been deprecated for a while now. Any answer involving mysql, is wrong and terrible advice. With "developer" in your name, I hope you are not using mysql still.

Comment: Yup i don't use mysql anymore i use PDO  @Wade